# Storing NSMutableArray of UIViews in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have read several posts about this but I'm not able to fix the error. If someone could please help.

Here is the code I use. I have an NSMutableArray called list.

```
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
prefs=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]retain];

if ([prefs arrayForKey:@"list"]) {
    list=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[prefs objectForKey:@"list"]];
}
else {
    list=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}    
}

-(void)saveData
 {
   NSLog(@"saving data!");
  [prefs setObject:list forKey:@"list"];
 }
- (void)dealloc {

[self saveData];
[prefs synchronize];
[prefs release];

 }
```

Comment: you shouldn't store/retain/release the preferences singleton -- just access it where you need it`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] ...]` and remove your implementation of the ivar.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store UIView instances in the user defaults, but only objects that can be serialized in a property list (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH5-SW1)) Also, as @Justin said, do not retain or release the defaults object.

Comment: The UIView could easily be converted to NSData, which is a perfectly valid type for NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. However, I had earlier read that you cannot save an NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults so I attempted to convert it to NSData and then use it.

Here's my ViewController.m file:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self=[[calViewController alloc]init];
if (self!=nil) {
    self.list=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"list"];
}
return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
 {
  [aCoder encodeObject:list forKey:@"list"];
 }
```

And here's my AppDelegate.m file:

```
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
NSLog(@"Application did finish launching");
defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray=[defaults objectForKey:@"lastArray"];
if (dataRepresentingSavedArray!=nil) {
    NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
    if (oldSavedArray != nil)
    {
        listAr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
    else
    {
        listAr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"listAr: %@",listAr);
    }

}
}

 -(void) applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
   {
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:listAr] forKey:@"lastArray"];        
   }
```

I've never used UserDefaults before and I absolutely confused. I've read all the docs but I don't seem to be getting it right!

**EDIT:**

```
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
NSLog(@"Application did finish launching");
defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"lastArray"]) {
    NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray=[defaults objectForKey:@"lastArray"];

if (dataRepresentingSavedArray!=nil) {
    NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
    if (oldSavedArray != nil)
        listAr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
    }
}
    else
    {
        listAr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"listAr: %@",listAr);
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens is that console shows that program enters 'ApplicationDidFinishLaunching', but my Simulator shows only a black screen. I will post an edit above, but despite the change in code there was no change.

Comment: Also, for some very strange reason, it enters the first if statement and traverses down all the way to 'listAr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWith ....]' when on the first call it should only be entering the else loop.

Comment: Okay I found the error. But now I get the following error! 
2011-02-18 12:20:12.035 cal[2423:207] *** Assertion failure in -[UICGColor encodeWithCoder:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1145.66/UIColor.m:679
2011-02-18 12:20:12.036 cal[2423:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only support RGBA or the White color space, this method is a hack.'